# Arcwise connected sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a nonempty open subset of $\textbf{R}^n$. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by $x \sim y$ if and only if there is a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ contained in $X$. Show the following:

1) $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$,

2) any equivalence class for $\sim$ is an open set in $\textbf{R}^n$, and

3) any equivalence class is relatively closed in $X$.

I was able to show (1) and (2). I am struggling with (3). I am trying to show that there exists a closed set $Y$ in $\textbf{R}^n$ such that $X \cap Y$ is an equivalence class, but seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $A$ be an equivalence class. We need to show that $X\setminus A$ is an opens set in $X$. Can we write $X\setminus A$ as a union of open subsets of $X$?

Comment: So if $x \in X \setminus A$ then $x \in X$ and $x \not\in A$. Relative to $X$ this implies $x \in X$. Since $X$ is open there exists an open ball around every point in $X$. Therefore there exists an open ball around every point in $X \setminus A$ so $X \setminus A$ is open?

Comment: Not quite because the arbitrary open ball around $x$ might intersect $A$. Instead, since $x\in X$, $x$ is in one of the equivalence classes of the relation $\sim$. What do we already know about those equivalence classes?

Comment: We know that the equivalence classes are open. Do they also have to be disconnected? Otherwise, if A and B were two equivalence classes with a nonempty intersection, then they would be the same equivalence class. So $X \setminus A$ is a union of disjoint open sets and therefore open?

Comment: First off, yes, you've got it. that is the easiest way (I think) to prove that $A$ is closed. Good job. Second, the union of open sets is always open, regardless of whether or not the sets are disjoint. Your union can include infinitely many copies of the same equivalence class class if you like. That is fine.

Comment: But the point is that $X\setminus A$ is equal to the union of all the other equivalence classes of $\sim$ in $X$. All the equivalence classes are open, so $X\setminus A$ is open.

Comment: Great, this makes sense now. Thanks!